# How to get rid of duplicate interface definition for class 'STEDataSheet'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

Even after reading the other posts like this one, I have not been able to find the duplicate interface definition, nor have I been able to fix this using any previous method mentioned on StackOverflow.
I tried turning `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` into: `#import "Ukit.h"` like another post suggested, along with everything else, and still nothing.
How else can I try and fix this?!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface STEDataSheet : NSObject {        // error found: Duplicate interface definition for class 'STEDataSheet'
    NSMutableArray *_rows;
    NSString *_dataSheetPath;
    NSString *_documentsPath;
    NSString *_persistenceName;
}

@property (atomic) NSString *sheetId;       // error found: property has a previous declaration

@property (atomic) NSArray *rows;           // error found: property has a previous declaration

@property (atomic) NSUUID *latestLoadId;    // error found: property has a previous
```

Comment: Do a global search for STEDataSheet in your code. If it has two `@interface` declarations, that's the problem. Otherwise, you probably have a double `import` somewhere, so look for imports of this file. Also make sure you have not somehow included the file twice in the app target build phase.

Comment: I've tried everything except your last point. How do i check for two files in the app target build phase @matt

Comment: Can you post your project somewhere? I'm betting I can just track down the problem for you.

Comment: I actually just figured it out! You were right i included the file twice somehow

Comment: I knew it. I've done it myself. :)

Comment: Haha thanks! Helped from past mistakes i like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface STEDataSheet : NSObject {        // error found: Duplicate interface definition for class 'STEDataSheet'
    NSMutableArray *rows;
    NSString *_dataSheetPath;
    NSString *_documentsPath;
    NSString *_persistenceName;
}

@property (atomic) NSString *sheetId;       // error found: property has a previous declaration

@property (atomic) NSArray *rows;           // error found: property has a previous declaration

@property (atomic) NSUUID *latestLoadId;    // error found: property has a previous
```

maybe you can find something difference about the property:
like this:

@property (atomic) NSArray *rows;

_rows

self.row

Hope it helps;